# How to write JUnit for Rest Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have written Rest controller as follows:

```
@RestController

public class RegisterRestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")

    public RegisterResponseObject createProspect(
            @Valid @RequestBody ProfileBean profileBean) throws Exception {

    //If validation passes do something
}

}
```

Here, if validation fails I am handling exception in Controller advice and sending error object back to client.

How to test this controller with JUnit for validation erros.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) that can perform requests. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-framework) is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling all the errors using controller advice in normal client request, you can do the same in JUnit also.

While testing controller classes, we build MockMvc object and then set the custom controller advice to that. This way when ever there is any exception in the method in controller classes, it will first go to controller advice and then return to JUnit test.

For example :

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.customController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new CustomControllerAdvice()).build();
}
```

This should help in testing the controller.
 
Note : I have tested this with Spring 4 version